# Magento Admin Panel PayPal Configuration Layout is Messed

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I have Magento 1.7 installation and it's whole Paypal layout is messed up, I don't know the reason. I reinstall all the modules using Magento connect. No luck, and I uploaded the core folder again from original Magento installation. "Mage_Paypal" module is enabled.Clear all cache.Also When I click on the Config button not showing settings.

Still the problem there.

Can anyone help me for solve this?

Here is screenshots.

[image: Screen-1]

---

[image: Screen-2]

---

[image: Screen-3]

[image: Screen-4]

Comment: This does not occur in a clean install. Maybe you are using some historic browser like MS IE 7 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem.
After some searching found out I had to update the Avalanche Theme to
version 1.3.2 (for magento 1.7+). Check https://fastdivision.com/themes/avalanche/members/download/.

Hope this helps